# PI Function in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating an SSIS package to import a csv file to a database. One of the steps is a "Derived Column" step that uses expressions to derive additional fields that will end up being written in the database.

Most of them are string concatenations or simple calculations and I have no issues with that.

I'm having issues with a calculation that requires the PI value. I can't seem to find it under "Mathematical Functions" for instance. Is there a way of invoking this function with expressions or do I have to use a script for this?

I would like to use something like this:

```
pi() * diameter_bar * diameter_bar / 4 * (CEILING(length_bar_bs / 25) * 25) * num_bars * 7850 * 0.000000001 / 1000
```

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: probably the best work around is a constant with the precision you need for example 3.14159265359 and to make it easier you can simplify all your constants as one coefficient

Comment: That might work, I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Jayvee, that was a good suggestion. I had to cast the derived column using (DT_NUMERIC,38,16) to get the desired scale and now the value calculates as expected. Many thanks.